# Firemonkey tEdit OnPaint

Tags: firemonkey, paint, rad-studio

I have a `tEdit` and I want to paint it's rect with a different set of `Fill` and `Stroke` colors. I coded as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate (Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.OnPaint := HandleEditPaint;
end;

procedure TForm1.HandleEditPaint (Sender: tObject; Canvas: tCanvas; const aRect: tRectF);
begin
  Canvas.BeginScene;
  Canvas.Fill  .Color := TAlphaColorRec.Aqua;
  Canvas.Fill  .Kind  := TBrushKind.bkSolid;
  Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Red;
  Canvas.Stroke.Kind  := TBrushKind.bkSolid;
  Canvas.FillRect (aRect, 0, 0, AllCorners, 1, TCornerType.Bevel);
  Canvas.DrawRect (aRect, 0, 0, AllCorners, 1, TCornerType.Bevel);
  Canvas.EndScene;
end;
```

It paints the control's rect properly, but it cannot be focused because when clicking on the Control, it enters in a loop that trigger's `HandleEditPaint` non stop. How can I avoid this to happen? I know that in painting the control's rect, I must take care of the control's text too, but I should concern about the mouse cursor either? Is there a way to achieve this behavior using styles?

Comment: maybe the best way it to make to TEdit transparent and put it on the top on a Trectangle that you resize to the size of the Tedit

Comment: I'm already doing this way. But I'm looking for a solution that does not involve that trick. Besides, I want to understand why HandleEditPaint is triggered non stop.

Comment: You should NOT be calling `(Begin|End)Scene` in an `OnPaint` handler at all. They are called automatically by the control for you. [This is documented behavior](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.BeginScene).

Comment: @Remy. Apparently this is not what triggers the OnPaint Handler:

From the link you posted: Tip: Notice that calling BeginScene in the OnPaint event handlers `has no effect`, because BeginScene is called before the OnPaint event handler runs. This guarantees that painting always occurs in OnPaint without requiring extra and probably unexpected code to allow drawing to have an effect. (my outlight).